# PHP Determining client URL type

Tags: php, curl

I'm currently writing a PHP script that receives a user inputted URL which points to a file on the users server. I'm currently doing this very basically using the cURL library and `$url = $_POST['url']` as variable url. However throughout my research I've found that I have to types of url that might be problematic when using the cURL:

- URL is SSL or TSL: Currently I'm matching the `$url` with `https://` to catch this.
- URL is username / password protected: I can catch this by matching a `:` followed by an `@`

My question is however, is it possible, using PHP to determine if the URL is SSL and/or password protected if the submitted url simply reads `www.something.com`? In this case I would need to alert the user that more information is required, and that they would need to supply a .pem file and/or username + password. 
I'm thinking of catching a cURL thrown error, but I'm not quite sure which.
Best Regards

Comment: _“I'm thinking of catching a cURL thrown error, but I'm not quite sure which.”_ – how bout setting up a test page for each scenario, and seeing what response/errors you get?

Comment: Slightly OT but you should really be using php's parse_url for, well, parsing urls -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: @Crisp true thats much more efficient!

Answer (score 1):

If URL is SSL, then download [certification bundle](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) (http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) file at the curl website and save it on your server and then include it in your PHP curl script,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, 'cacert.pem');
```

User doesn't have to provide `.pem` file. `cert.pem` will handle the SSL.

Comment: That's interesting! Will that work as a stand in for every imaginable certificate?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Over some period of time you may have to update the `cacert.pem` with latest version (which might have newer certifications). You can check here, http://curl.haxx.se/ca/